# Overwrite df.to_json file

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm building a real-time Twitter sentiment analysis web using Python. I want the results of the analysis to be stored in a json format file to be used as historical data for each search that was carried out. How can I overwrite all the search data in one file?
The data was originally stored in the Pandas dataframe on a temporary basis, so I converted it to an array in json

```
headings = ("Tweet", "Sentimen")
data = list(zip(tweets['tweet_text'], sentiment))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Tweet', 'Sentimen'])
df.to_json(r'Export_DataFrame6.json', orient='records', indent=4)

a_file = open("Export_DataFrame6.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(a_file)
d = json_object[0]
d['Tweet'] = "Testing"
d['Sentimen'] = "Negative"
a_file = open("Export_DataFrame6.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, a_file)
a_file.close()
```

update code:

```
 headings = ("Tweet", "Sentimen")
data = list(zip(tweets['tweet_text'], sentiment))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Tweet', 'Sentimen'])
df.to_json(r'Export_DataFrame6.json', orient='records', indent=4)

a_file = open("Export_DataFrame6.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(a_file)
a_file.close()

d = json_object[0]
d['Tweet'] = tweets['tweet_text']
d['Sentimen'] = sentiment
a_file = open("Export_DataFrame6.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, a_file)
a_file.close()
```

error: TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

Comment: do you mean you want to add data to already created json file? if that is your question that's not possible with pandas. you have to use `json` module

Comment: @deadshot yes, thats what i mean. But i already convert the pandas dataframe to json, is it still not allowed? I've tried using json.dump and json.load to try to enter 1 data that I type myself into the file, and it works.

Comment: where you stuck now?

Comment: @deadshot I want to add tweets['tweet_text'] variable and the sentiment variable (every time I do analysis) into the json file that already fill with previous analysis. What I said previously worked, is when I manually fill it in by myself

Comment: manually means using `json` module?

Comment: @deadshot yes, like on lines 8-9 of the source code that I put above. I want to change "Testing" with tweets['tweet_text'] and "Negative" with sentiment, but its getting error

Comment: can you share the error and also update the code

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting stuck on this line:

```
d = json_object[0]
```

because you think you have a json object but don't, and when try to use [0] you get the error. Without seeing the json file, it's a rough guess.

can you open your file this way?

```
with open('Export_DataFrame6.json', 'rb') as f:
    json_object = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

and then try

```
d = json_object[0]

or 

d = json.loads(json_object)[0]
```

Comment: okay, thank you so much, but its already solved with json append